# ListFragment highlight the selected item in the list?

Tags: android, tabs, android-listfragment

I have a listFragment and I want to highlight the selected item in the list.
I have a layout with two fragments. The left hand fragment is a ListFragment using a SimpleCursorAdaptor, the right hand one is populated with details about the item selected from the list in the left fragment. I'm trying to figure out how to make sure the selected item from the ListFragment stays highlighted until another item in the list is selected.

Please Suggest any good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

**ListFragment** highlight the selected item for that just add into your suitable Lifecycle method of `Listfragment`

```
getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.fragment_listselector);
```

**EDIT :**

for more about this refer this **[Link](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html)** & check Source code of it thats works for Me!

Comment: I tried this getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.fragment_listselector); in life cycle of Activity its not working.

Comment: you should put in your Listfragment

Comment: when u select list item it will shows color on selected item and another activity will execute in Right Fragment or window after coming back that selected item color will goes. its should be selected.